# Wix обновления программы

Tags: обновления, wix

Задание вот какое:

1. Я уже написала инсталлятор для программы.
2. Теперь еще нужно сделать так, что когда выпустится 2 версия для этой программы, запустят установочник, он определит, что стоит 1 версия и не заменит конфиг-файл программы.
3. А вот когда выпустится 3 версия и ее будут устанавливать на компьютеры, то конфиг файл должен измениться (независимо от того 1 версия стояла или уже 2-ая).
4. Когда выпустится 4 версия, то (ВОТ ТУТ Непонятно :( ) 
            1.если стояла 1 или 2 версия, то конфиг-файл меняется 
   `            2.если обнаружена 3 версия, то конфиг-файл не меняется

При всем при этом! Необходимо, чтобы каждая новая версия программы могла бы быть установлена без наличия на компьютере какой-либо предыдущей версии (то есть просто взять и установить на комп сразу 4 версию - и все должно работать)

Я правильно понимаю, что нужно для каждой версии программы писать свой инсталлятор в WIX (то есть создавать отдельный проект в Visual Studio)?

Comment: @Tatyana Druzenko, Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем вы видите проблему, как ее воспроизвести и т. д.

Comment: Задание вот какое: 
1. Я уже написала инсталятор для программы.
2. Теперь еще нужно сделать так, что когда выпустится 2 версия для этой программы, запустят установочник, он определит, что стоит 1 версия и не заменит конфиг-файл программы.
3. А вот когда выпустится 3 версия и ее будут устанавливать на компьютеры, то конфиг файл должен измениться (независимо от того 1 версия стояла или уже 2-ая).
4. Когда выпустится 4 версия, то (ВОТ ТУТ Непонятно :( )
1.если стояла 1 или 2 версия, то конфиг-файл меняется
2.если обнаружена 3 версия, то конфиг-файл не меняется

Comment: При всем при этом! Необходимо, чтобы каждая новая версия программы могла бы быть установлена без наличия на компьютере какой-либо предыдущей версии (то есть просто взять и установить на комп сразу 4 версию - и все должно работать)

Я правильно понимаю, что нужно для каждой версии программы писать свой инсталлятор в WIX (то есть создавать отдельный проект в Visual Studio)?

Answer (score 0):

В `wix 3.0` для `visual studio` можно написать для каждой версии свой инсталлятор, но обычно работа идёт над одной версией инсталлятора, который обновляется в каждом релизе.

При работе с версиями помните про изменения `guid`.

Для того, чтобы задавать условия для обновления файлов используйте `condition`, который будет сравнивать версии.